# performance when looping through entry collection

Tags: java, xpages

I have a very - for me - mysterious effect:

In my Xpage i have a little java bean, in which I loop through an entry collection, build with getallentriesbykey(username) (gets me about 200 entries.

viewA has 2 sorted columns: UserName + customerID,

viewB has 2 sorted columns: UserName + weeknumber(text) of delivery

with viewA the loop needs less than one second, 
but with viewB the loop needs more than 10 seconds!
And what's really crazy (for me): when i place the column with customerID behind the weeknumber in viewB, and sort it, then the loop is fast again!

```
        ViewEntryCollection mycoll = myview.getAllEntriesByKey(myuser);
            myentry = mycoll.getFirstEntry();
            System.out.println("Start loop");
            while (myentry != null) {
            /* of course I do sth here, but the effect is the same 
            with nothing in, like in this example*/
                tmpentry = mycoll.getNextEntry();
                myentry.recycle();
                myentry = tmpentry; 
                // tmpentry.recycle();
            } 
            System.out.println("End loop");
```

I am really confused ... maybe someone can bring some light ... ?
Thanks in advance, Uwe

update:

It stays mysterious:

myview.getAllEntriesByKey(myuser,key1) gives me let's say 200 entries - loops quite fast. 
myview.getAllEntriesByKey(myuser,key2) gives me only 50 entries - needs 6 times longer to loop through.

The db has 20.000 docs, all with reader fields. Therefore (I am new to xpages, not to lotus notes ... ;-)) I first collected them by "myuser", all views have the multivalue reader item in the 1st sorted column. In my understanding the collections contain only docs which the user is allowed to see. So I don't see the difference beetwen (myuser,key1)- and (myuser,key2)-collection.

Comment: Probably doing a database lookup of some kind whenever you call getNextEntry, different columns in the lookup will have different results based on indexes and such.

Comment: The lookup is quite fast, in both cases, the view index is built by the sorted columns. The views look almost the same, only the sorted columns are different

Comment: I guess I'd focus more on the views.  What's the forumla of this number column?  What's the selection formula for the views?  Are you sure their the same?  Is "show response docs in heirchary" the same?  What if you actually deleted the bad view and rebuilt it from scratch?  any difference there?

Comment: David, that was my first guess too, that the view is "somehow kaputt". --- So I built it new: It's just a copy from the "good one", and all I changed was the sorting columns: disable it for column 2(customerID), enable it for column 6 (weeknumber). 

The lookup (getentriesbykey) is fast in both cases, what is so slow is the looping.

Comment: The number of docs returned will have an affect onm the time taken to run the loop, but from what you say it's a similar number ? Could it be that in the slower view, there are lots of documents hidden from the xpage by reader-fields ? That would cause it to run more slowly because it has to sift trhough what you're allowed to see first, although I'm unsure whether the time-hit would be as getAllEntriesByKey is called, or as you traverse through the collection.

Comment: When you initialise the view, it's best to call setAutoUpdate(false). Otherwise, view index updates may affect performance unexpectedly. This is one of the benefits OpenNTF Domino API can offer out-of-the-box

Comment: It stays mysterious: myview.getAllEntriesByKey(myuser,key1) gives me let's say 200 entries - loops quite fast. 

myview.getAllEntriesByKey(myuser,key2) gives me only 50 entries - needs 6 times longer to loop through.

the db has 20.000 docs, all with reader fields. Therefore (I am new to xpages, not to lotus notes ... ;-)) I first collected them by "myuser", all views have the reader item in the 1st sorted column. In my understanding the collections contain only docs which the user is allowed to see. 

So I don't see the difference beetwen (myuser,key1)- and (myuser,key2)-collection.

Comment: Paul, I tried setAutoUpdate(false): It doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the ViewNavigator classes instead? They are better optimised for iteration performance and are what's used by XPages dominoView datasource and picker dataProviders, where possible.

I haven't done testing on ViewEntry navigation performance, so I'm not sure what will be quick / not. As David says, I think your view is going to have an impact. Maybe adding timers before and after getting values from the ViewEntry. It *sounds* like the view has an index of the sorted column values, which is being used for the first loop; but it needs to actually use getColumnValues() for the second loop. That's just a hypothesis though, I've no idea of its plausibility.

Comment: Using the ViewNavigator will definitely be faster. See this article for some tips on how to set that up: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Fast_Retrieval_of_View_Data_Using_the_ViewNavigator_Cache